# How to change background of clicked checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

So I am trying to make a exam page. I have choices with checkboxes. And when a choice is selected, I want its background to change. But I am having some issues.

You can see the codes and screen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tLr49jg6/2/)

Here is HTML code below:

```
<div class="questions">
  <div class="questions-left-column">
    <div class="question-area">
      <p>QUESTION</p>
      <div class="choices">
        <div class="choice answer" id="1answer">
          <input id="choice-1a" type="radio" name="radio1" />
          <label for="choice-1a">
            <strong>A.</strong>
            Option A
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="choice">
          <input id="choice-1b" type="radio" name="radio1" />
          <label for="choice-1b">
            <strong>B.</strong>
            Option B
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="choice">
          <input id="choice-1c" type="radio" name="radio1" />
          <label for="choice-1c">
            <strong>C.</strong>
            Option C
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="choice">
          <input id="choice-1d" type="radio" name="radio1" />
          <label for="choice-1d">
            <strong>D.</strong>
            Option D
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="choice">
          <input id="choice-1e" type="radio" name="radio1" />
          <label for="choice-1e">
            <strong>E.</strong>
            Option E
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="show-answer-button-container">
        <label class="show-answer">
          <fieldset hidden class="answers">
            <strong>Correct Answer: </strong>
            A
          </fieldset>
          <button type="button" onclick="checkAnswers()">Check Answers</button>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is CSS code below:

```
.selectt {
  display: none;
}
.questions {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 0.3px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
}
.questions-left-column {
  flex-direction: column;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  padding-right: 100px;
}
.question-area {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: 0.3px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
}
.choice {
  width: 350px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  align-content: left;
  justify-self: center;
  border: 1px solid darkgrey;
}

.choice input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background: rgb(226, 182, 182);
  cursor: default;
}
input {
  visibility: hidden;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.show-answer-button-container {
  margin: 10px;
}

.show-answer {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  align-items: right;
  padding: 0.1rem;
  border: 0.5px solid rgb(119, 108, 108);
  background: rgb(133, 183, 212);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
}
```

Here is JS code below:

```
function checkAnswers() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("choice answer");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
  }
}
```

Here are my problems:

- When a choice is selected, only background of text is changing. The background of whole option box should change.
- When 'Show Answer' button is clicked. Correct answer is shown with green background but if the selected choice is same with answer text's background is being purple and box's background is being green.

Thank you for help!

Comment: _"The background of whole option box should change."_ - you are currently only changing the background of the label. And you _can't_ change the parent container via CSS alone, because CSS can not select upwards in the DOM. So if you want to do this part completely in CSS alone - then you need to see to it, that the label element covers the whole box.

Comment: How I can do that? I do not necessarly do with CSS.

Comment: Add `position:absolute` for the radio buttons, to take them out of the normal layout flow. Then remove the padding from `.choice`, and put it on the `label` elements instead - and add `display:block` to them.

Comment: Thank you this worked. But now when Show Answer button is clicked, if the chosen option is correct, background is not turning to green?

Comment: It _is_ turning green - but it is the background of the div element, which is now _completely_ covered by the label, and that has its own background. So set the background for the label instead.

Comment: I couldn't understand what you said correct I guess. I couldn't fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

via javascript you need to add  an `onclick` event on the `label` from which you can access the parent style and update background.

You need to loop on them to first add that click event and then loop again to reset the correct background value on click.

here is a basic example (that can surely be optimized), adding/removing a class.

```js
function checkAnswers() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("choice answer");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
  }
}
/* added */

const choices = document.querySelectorAll(".choice label");// get them all
// add onclick on labels found
for (let i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
  choices[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
    check(i);
  });
}
// triggered from the label click 
function check(el) {
  // reset all to none
  for (let ii = 0; ii < choices.length; ii++) {
    choices[ii].parentNode.classList.remove("selected");
  }
  // reset the label's parent classList
  choices[el].parentNode.classList.add("selected");
}
```

```css
.selectt {
  display: none;
}

.questions {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 0.3px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
}

.questions-left-column {
  flex-direction: column;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  padding-right: 100px;
}

.question-area {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: 0.3px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
}

.choice {
  width: 350px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  align-content: left;
  justify-self: center;
  border: 1px solid darkgrey;
}

.choice input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  padding: 0.5rem;

  cursor: default;
}

input {
  visibility: hidden;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.show-answer-button-container {
  margin: 10px;
}

.show-answer {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  align-items: right;
  padding: 0.1rem;
  border: 0.5px solid rgb(119, 108, 108);
  background: rgb(133, 183, 212);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
}

.selected {
  background: rgb(226, 182, 182);
}
```

```html
<div class="questions">
  <div class="questions-left-column">
    <div class="question-area">
      <p>QUESTION</p>
      <div class="choices">
        <div class="choice answer" id="1answer">
          <input id="choice-1a" type="radio" name="radio1" />
          <label for="choice-1a">
            <strong>A.</strong>
            Option A
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="choice">
          <input id="choice-1b" type="radio" name="radio1" />
          <label for="choice-1b">
            <strong>B.</strong>
            Option B
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="choice">
          <input id="choice-1c" type="radio" name="radio1" />
          <label for="choice-1c">
            <strong>C.</strong>
            Option C
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="choice">
          <input id="choice-1d" type="radio" name="radio1" />
          <label for="choice-1d">
            <strong>D.</strong>
            Option D
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="choice">
          <input id="choice-1e" type="radio" name="radio1" />
          <label for="choice-1e">
            <strong>E.</strong>
            Option E
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="show-answer-button-container">
        <label class="show-answer">
          <fieldset hidden class="answers">
            <strong>Correct Answer: </strong>
            A
          </fieldset>
          <button type="button" onclick="checkAnswers()">Check Answers</button>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/symfou/phw25ydg/26/

class modified:

```
.choice {
    position: relative;
    width: 350px;
    padding: .5rem;
    align-content: left;
    justify-self: center;
    border: 1px solid darkgrey;
}

.choice input[type="radio"]:checked  + label strong{
    padding-left: 25px;
}

.choice input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    padding: .5rem 0;
    background-color:rgb(226, 182, 182);
    cursor: default;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working Code using onchange event in input

```js
function checkAnswers() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("choice answer");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
  }
}

function changeSelection() {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('option'), function(el) {
    let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("choice answer");
    if (el.checked) {
      el.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(226, 182, 182)";
    } else {
      el.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.selectt {
    display : none;
}
.questions {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    border: .3px solid gray;
    padding: 10px;    
}
.questions-left-column {
    flex-direction: column;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    width: 400px;
    padding-right: 100px;
    }
.question-area {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    border: .3px solid gray;
    padding: 10px;
}
.choice {
    
    width: 350px;
    padding: .5rem;
    align-content: left;
    justify-self: center;
    border: 1px solid darkgrey;
}

input {
    visibility:hidden;
}

label {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.show-answer-button-container {
    margin: 10px;
}

.show-answer {
    margin-top: .5rem;
    align-items: right;
    padding: .1rem;
    border: .5px solid rgb(119, 108, 108);
    background: rgb(133, 183, 212);
    color: white;
    border-radius: .2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="questions">
  <div class="questions-left-column">
    <div class="question-area">
      <p>QUESTION</p>
      <div class="choices">
        <div class="choice answer" id="1answer">
          <input id="choice-1a" type="radio" name='radio1' class="option" onchange="changeSelection()">
          <label for="choice-1a">
            <strong>A.</strong>
            Option A
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="choice">
          <input id="choice-1b" type="radio" name='radio1' class="option" onchange="changeSelection()">
          <label for="choice-1b">
            <strong>B.</strong>
            Option B
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="choice">
          <input id="choice-1c" type="radio" name='radio1' class="option" onchange="changeSelection()">
          <label for="choice-1c">
            <strong>C.</strong>
            Option C
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="choice">
          <input id="choice-1d" type="radio" name='radio1' class="option" onchange="changeSelection()">
          <label for="choice-1d">
            <strong>D.</strong>
            Option D
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="choice">
          <input id="choice-1e" type="radio" name='radio1' class="option" onchange="changeSelection()">
          <label for="choice-1e">
            <strong>E.</strong>
            Option E
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="show-answer-button-container">
        <label class="show-answer">

          <fieldset hidden class="answers">
            <strong>Correct Answer: </strong>
            A
          </fieldset>

          <button type="button" onclick="checkAnswers()">Check Answers</button>
```